# Synaptics: select by words (triple click) using touchpad

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, synaptics

I switched from my old asus laptop to a new dell xps 15 and the touchpad is great except selection of text by entire words. To select entire words in my old laptop I used triple click (which emulates two real mouse clicks) and I used to move my cursor from the selected word to other words and the selection expanded word by word until I released the touchpad. In my new notebook, if I use triple click it will select a word but **if I don't apply enough pressure after that** it will release the selection and I can't select next words. All other gestures (include simple selection which activates by double click) work fine and I think the problem is in configuration.

`synclient` has so many configuration variables which makes me frustrated. I tried to decrease `FingerLow` option but it seems to make no difference.

Comment: did you check the mouse settings?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: in Settings>Mouse&Touchpad

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want the touchpad to be more sensitive, try the first answer in this link:

https://superuser.com/questions/229839/reduce-laptop-touch-pad-sensitivity-in-ubuntu

But don't just copy the values he pasted, read carefully what he says about what values adjust what, and play around with it a bit.

The second answer there also might help you.

(also keep in mind that this is an answer for an older version of ubuntu so it might not work)